# Change Ext JS Toolbar orientation (Outside the config)

Tags: jquery, extjs, extjs3

Is there a painless way to change an Ext JS toolbar orientation? Something like changing a ***tbar*** to a ***bbar*** (outside the config)

I'm trying to do this in Ext JS 3.4

I know I can override the config and change the toolbar orientation. But I was wondering if there was someone out there who was smart enough to do it with a few lines of code.

Comment: at what point? do you mean programatically after component is rendered?

Comment: After render would work too. I basically want the tbar to be bbar when the component is shown / becomes visible to the user.

Comment: so why not make it so in the config?

Comment: Well, my config has it as a tbar. I wanna know how I can change that tbar to a bbar before the panel containing the toolbar gets rendered. The application that I'm working is a multi-tenant one. It must look like a tbar in certain scenarios and a bbar in others. So I need to change it outside my config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to change initial config is to pass an overriding config during instantiation.
For example if you have a definition of a panel with a tbar:

```
Ext.define('MyPanel',{
  extend:'Ext.panel.Panel',
  tbar: [{text:'myButton'}]
  ...
});
```

you can override it's config when you instantiate it:

```
Ext.create('MyPanel',{
  tbar:undefined,
  bbar: [{text:'myButton'}]
  ...
});
```